# Git clone stderr

Tags: git, atom-editor

He estado buscando, pero no doy con la solución.

Al usar el editor Atom con la funcionalidad de clonarme un repositorio de Git obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> stderr: "git" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
> programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable
> ```

[image: No se como solucionar el problema de la imagen]

Gracias a todo el que me ayude.

Comment: ¿Podrías al menos describir tu error? Una imagen así sirve para acompañar una pregunta, no para definirla. Pensemos en quienes están con dispositivos con pantallas chicas o con problemas de vista, o quienes tengan el mismo error e intenten buscar la solución

Comment: Mi error gracias por la sugerencia, soy nuevo en **stackoverflow**, mira me sale **stderr: "git" no se reconoce como un comando in o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable**, cuando voy a clonar un repositorio con **git clone**.

Te agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no tienes instalado git, o al menos no se encuetra en la variable de entorno $PATH

Comment: Tengo instalado git lo tengo en entá ruta C:\Program Files\Git\bin, pero no se cual es la variable de entorno $PATH para **git clone**, por que el PATH de **git plus** si funciona.

Te agradezco si me ayudas :)

Comment: estas en windows o linux/unix?

Comment: puedes revisar si tienes instalado git, abriendo la consola y escribiendo `git --version`

Comment: estoy en Windows

Comment: `$ git --version
git version 2.13.0.windows.1
`

Comment: me puedes decir que IDE o UI es ese?

Comment: Es un editor llamado Atom